# Barh raises an error unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'float'

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

When I wanna put ytickslabels on my graph it says

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'float'
```

Its driving me insane. My attempt at code, using Python 2.7.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, plot, xlabel, ylabel, legend, title, close, barh, ylim, bar
import numpy as np

a = [u'name1', u'name2', u'name3']
b = np.array([6.35, 6.414, 6.400])
figure('bar', figsize=(11,5))
barh(a, b, align='center', alpha=0.5)
xlabel('yield (%)')
```

What am I missing? Its because a is a list and b is an array?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this on Python 3.6

Comment: yeah Im on python 2.7. Sorry

Comment: This is independent of the python version. Your code will work fine with any matplotlib version >= 2.1.

Comment: Ah thank you! I tried in python 3 and it works.

Comment: Well, that is, because when you use python3 your matplotlib version will have been updated.